# file operation write is not happening in new line

Tags: c, linux, file-io

Hi following code sample seems to have some problem or either it has to do something with OS internals.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>

    static void usage();
    #define MONC_AM_CONF "/tmp/monc.conf"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int ch;
        char list[200];
        int len;
        int fd;

        memset(list,0,200);
        if (argc < 11) {
                usage();
                exit(1);
        }

        while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "N:S:P:H:R:")) != -1) {
                switch (ch) {
                        case 'N':
                                len = strlen(optarg) + 2;
                                sprintf(list,"%s::",optarg);
                                break;
                        case 'S':
                                sprintf(list+len,"%s::",optarg);
                                len = len + strlen(optarg) + 2;
                                break;
                        case 'P':
                                sprintf(list+len,"%s::",optarg);
                                len = len + strlen(optarg) + 2;
                                break;
                        case 'H':
                                sprintf(list+len,"%s::",optarg);
                                len = len + strlen(optarg) + 2;
                                break;
                        case 'R':
                                sprintf(list+len,"%s ",optarg);
                                len = len + strlen(optarg);
                                break;
                        default:
                                printf ("You specified a parameter I don't "
                                                "know about.\n");
                                break;
                }
        }
        argc -= optind;
        argv += optind;

        printf("Total length of string is %d\n",len);
        printf("The string is %s\n",list);

        fd = open(MONC_AM_CONF, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0644);
        lseek(fd, 0,SEEK_END);
        write(fd,list,len);
        close(fd);

        return 0;
}

static void usage()
{
printf("Please provide the command in correct format\n");
printf("monc_am_config -N <Comp_Name> -S <Start Script Path> -P <Stop Script Path> -H <HealthCheck Script Path> -R <Recovery Policy>\n");

return ;
}
```

When I am issuing commands I am getting the output file each time different. 
I am expecting execution of this program each time should write the information in the new line but it is writing into the same line in the file.

Plz help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should append "\n" to list, i.e

```
list[len++] = '\n';
```

Comment: and hope that 199 characters is all that will ever be needed